# Why does localstorage update when ive loaded it in to another object, then make changes to that object?

Tags: javascript, object

Im building a "Diagnostic" view in my JS based app.

I load all of the localstorage in to a variable:

```
var diagnosticinformation = localStorage;
```

And then the idea is that I can output diagnosticinformation in to a text box:

```
textarea1.value = JSON.stringify(diagnosticinformation);
```

This all works fine.

However, before outputting the diagnosticinformation I would like to hide userToken and sharedpasscode for security purposes.

```
diagnosticinformation['userToken']="HIDDEN";
diagnosticinformation['sharedpasscode']="HIDDEN";
```

However, when i do this, the LocalStorage element is then also updated so userToken then become "HIDDEN" and the sharedpasscode also becomes "HIDDEN" **in the actual localstorage of the browser**, not just within diagnosticinformation

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Surely if object1 = object2 - I can alter object1 without it affecting object2 - however this isn't the case.

Comment: `diagnosticinformation` is just a *reference* to `localStorage`....not a copy of it

Comment: Clone the `localStorage` content with `var newMap = {}; for (var i in localStorage) newMap[i] = localStorage[i];`

Comment: When you do `var diagnosticinformation = localStorage;` (try to use const and let) you are not copying the object, you are creating a reference to it so if you update `localStorage` or `diagnosticinformation` then both objects will be updated as both are "connected". You can use  `Object.assign({}, localStorage)` to define `diagnosticinformation`